# How to set cache size in UIwebView?

Tags: ios, caching, uiwebview

I have an app of UIWebview, I open the webpage A, there are lots of images in webpage A.
so it was very slow when i was first time to open it. 
and i opened another webpage B and go back to webpage A, it was very fast and show images directly. 
then I opened lots of other webpage and go back to webpage A,
the webpage A was slow again, the webpage A did not change anyghing.

it looks like the uiwebivew cache size is not enough when i opened lots of other webpage,so it delete the old record.

how should i avoid this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you solved it??? I have the same question!! thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

See the [NSURLCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLCache/initWithMemoryCapacity%3adiskCapacity%3adiskPath%3a) documentation.

You could be able to set the cache value as follows:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1000000 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
[sharedCache release];
sharedCache = nil;
```